# How do you replace a couple tiles?

Tags: tile

So I finished laying wood plank ceramic tile using large format medium bed mortar. I used the Lash system and did this over three days, half on day one, one day off, then finished tonight. Some lessons learned included making sure to half the Lash pliers at the beginning, and more importantly NOT leaving in lash clips on the border stopping point. The clips bonded to the cured mortar and this created some lippage, most noticeable in a couple spots.

Question: what is the best way to remove a tile or two and replace them before I grout? I back buttered every tile and used a 1/2 inch trowel. Substrate is 3/4 plywood plus 1/4 backerboard plus layer of Hydro Ban.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a ceramic drill bit to add a series of holes within the tile you want to remove, then use a tile chisel or cold chisel to remove the pieces. Be patient.

TOH has a good article: 
https://www.thisoldhouse.com/how-to/how-to-replace-broken-tile

Answer (score -2):

just wack the centre of the tile with a hammer.  hard, not gently.  you want to shatter the tile, and not simply vibrate loose it and 10 other tiles around it.  once broken, just pick out the pieces, grind out the old mortar and install new tiles.  its really quite simple.